# Webservice SOAP XML request not work in Axis2 Webservice

Tags: web-services, request, soapui, apache-axis

```
I have a request with SOAPUI, work good:

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:webservice">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Notificacion>
         <as_xml_peticion><![CDATA[<G_PETICION>
                    <CABECERA>
                        <NOTIFICADOR>API</NOTIFICADOR>   
                    </CABECERA>
                    </G_PETICION>]]>
         </as_xml_peticion>


But when I make a Axis2 Webservice client java with WSDL:

String xml = <![CDATA[<G_PETICION>
                    <CABECERA>
                        <NOTIFICADOR>API</NOTIFICADOR>   
                    </CABECERA>
                    </G_PETICION>]]>;
tnofication.setAs_xml_peticion(xml);
notification.setNotificacion(tnofication);
WebserviceStub.NotificacionResponse response = proxy.notificacion(notification);
```

the response is:

Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
What is the problem?